# Overriding RazorView's RenderView method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a class which should scan the whole html view, parse it, and replace some elements inside the DOM. For that I decided to create a custom RazorView and override the RenderView method: I call the base.RenderView to get the writer populated, then get the string in it, parse it, and eventually change all I need.

But after that I should put the new string back to the writer for it to be rendered. And I can't get where to put it. Any clues?

Should I overwrite Render method instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this approach will get you some invalid HTML and/or XSS sooner or later. Why can't you just have a different version of the view with the changes, or a single version that renders certain parts conditionally?

Comment: Because I need this to work for ALL pages in my site

Comment: Why don't you render your view and then run an XSLT on the HTML that it returns?

Comment: Because I need to perform some operations on the html with c#

Comment: And you couldn't make these changes using a layout, or partial views, or any of the existing mechanisms. Your situation seems to be very ... special. Can you give any details?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders sorry. Wasn't aware of that. The basic idea is to create a runtime bundler and minificator. I scan the page html, load all elements of type <script>, <style> and <link>, get the files from the disc, budle, minify it, delete the elements and add a single file per type per page (with some exceptions, of course). Maybe I'll release it as open source as well

Comment: And what's wrong with the built-in bundling and minification in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: that it's different :) You need to compile your resources and every time you add a new file you have to add it to the configuration. More over, if you have an @import directive, the file it refers to won't be taken into account by the minifier, not to mention the inline script and style elements.

Comment: Moreover  I work for a company where back and front end developers roles are separated. So every time a front end developer adds a css or a js files, they have to inform backend developers to modify the configuration. This is error-prone for many many reasons. My solution leaves developers (front-end and back-end) free of all this concern, as the class takes care of the scripts once they have been rendered to the final page. No more configurations, no more compilation, no more fights. Easy peasy and everybody happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
    protected override void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, object instance)
    {
        //Create a temporary writer
        TextWriter w = new StringWriter();

        //And call the base method with it
        base.RenderView(viewContext,w,instance);

        //Now I get the HTML from the temp writer
        var html = w.ToString();

        //Do my things and change the HTML

        //And finally write the changes back to the main writer
        writer.Write(html);
    }
```

To be honest it's a little more complex than this, but this is the base I started from.